# Android View pager pagechangelistener onpageselected triggers all the time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

In Android View pager OnPageChangeListener onpageselected triggers all the time. I want to prevent that, if it is scrolled fastly. Also, the onpageselected method should be called only if the scroll stopped at a page. Is there any way to handle this situation?

Comment: Read this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html as you can see the interface has three callbacks, you cannot change when and if they are called you can only implement your logic inside it that completes your goal.

Comment: @NitroNbg thsx for the link. I'll check with this.